# Use the count() aggregation - Firestore Data for Swift App

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
    func fetch() async throws {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let snapshot = try await  Firestore.firestore().collection("notifications").document(uid).collection("user-notifications")
            .whereField("read", isEqualTo: "n")
            .limit(to: 10)
            .getDocuments()
        self.notifications = try snapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Notification.self) })
    }

    func fetch2() async throws {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("notifications").document(uid).collection("user-notifications")
            .whereField("read", isEqualTo: "n")
            .limit(to: 10)
        let countQuery = query.count
        let snapshot = try await countQuery.getAggregation(source: .server)
    }
```

I am trying to move from fetch() to fetch2() function like above so that I only show the count the notification number in my app.

I am not sure how to write the below part in the second function.

```
self.notifications = try snapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Notification.self)
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snapshot you are getting is a `AggregateQuerySnapshot` and contains a property called `count` which is the number of documents contained in the query as `NSInteger`. Then to convert it to `Int` you can just use `intValue`. See the example below:

```
func fetch2() async throws {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("notifications").document(uid).collection("user-notifications")
        .whereField("read", isEqualTo: "n")
        .limit(to: 10)
    let countQuery = query.count
    let snapshot = try await countQuery.getAggregation(source: .server)
    let count = snapshot.count.intValue
}
```

This way, every for every 1000 document counts, you just use 1 read operation.